# calling android method in unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have 2 question

1- does it necessary for the method that we are calling from unity to be placed in the mainActivity, Or we can make any activity static and call the the function present in those activities? Also i read in different forums about this that you should change the manifest file and make your plugin activity the main activity. Is it necessary to do it or we can call without doing this.

2- my second question is what if I want to call the unity function from android application. Can I do this by importing the unity project in android and then call the unity scriot function from the android activity.

I have already successfully called a function in unity from android. but in this i made android project the plugin. Now i want to do it the opposite i.e making the unity project plugin in eclipse.

At I should mention that I am creating a vuforia unity project like your not a simple unity project.

Comment: Any updates? im kind of in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

For your No.2 question, the answer is just call

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

then, write a c# function MethodName1 in a c# script and add the script to GameObjectName1.

UnityPlayer is a class in class.jar, this jar is in

(your unity install location):\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\androidplayer\bin

please import this jar to your eclipse project firstly.
hope it helpful. :)